# Threading problem while using PyQT app in Streamlit

Tags: pyqt5, streamlit

Due to the lack of control point selection software in python, I started using the [cpselect](https://github.com/hofmann-tobias/cpselect) tool implemented in PyQT. I fixed some issues there regarding matplotlib and started using it in my project. Now I create a dashboard using [streamlit](https://share.streamlit.io/) with a button that launches/calls the [cpselect function](https://github.com/hofmann-tobias/cpselect/blob/master/cpselect/cpselect.py). The first execution is fine and I can select my points and when leaving the window, I obtain the control points. While the windows opens I get the following log:

```
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

The problem is when I execute it a second time! The window displays without problems, I can select my points and everything. The log output changes to:

```
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QtWaylandClient::QWaylandDisplay(0x7fd850020370), parent's thread is QThread(0x7fd8508fb570), current thread is QThread(0x7fd852c2c410)
```

I am not sure on how to debug this, since it doesn't provide me where the problem happens. I have tried to change the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` variable in hopes that it is a problem with wayland, but it seems not to be the case. One time I got the log message:

```
QBasicTimer::stop: Failed. Possibly trying to stop from a different thread
QBasicTimer::stop: Failed. Possibly trying to stop from a different thread
QBasicTimer::stop: Failed. Possibly trying to stop from a different thread
QBasicTimer::stop: Failed. Possibly trying to stop from a different thread
QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
QBasicTimer::stop: Failed. Possibly trying to stop from a different thread
QBasicTimer::stop: Failed. Possibly trying to stop from a different thread
QBasicTimer::stop: Failed. Possibly trying to stop from a different thread
QBasicTimer::stop: Failed. Possibly trying to stop from a different thread
```

when I was switching it to `eglfs`, so maybe it is due to the `updateGUI` function slotted into the timer object.

Does someone have an idea or hint on how I would tackle this problem?

**EDIT 1**
Minimal working example:

```py
# pip install streamlit
import streamlit as st
# pip install cpselect
from cpselect.cpselect import cpselect

cps_btn = st.button('Open cpselect')

if cps_btn:
    points = cpselect('westconcordaerial.png', 'westconcordorthophoto.png')
```

Note: before executing, the provided fix has to be done in the `cpselect.py` file (probably located at `~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cpselect/cpselect.py`) provided [here](https://github.com/hofmann-tobias/cpselect/pull/5/commits/cf83871a23db49bdec6fd0a8389391cbb2ecdc97).

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags and don't use a comma-splice run-on.

Comment: The first wayland warning can probably be ignored, all the other warnings are self-explanatory, but their cause is unknown until you clarify *how* you're using streamlit *and* pyqt.

Comment: I have provided a mwe (or better said mnwe). The cpselect.py file is provided up there. Would it be possible to find out what is causing the error?